Why @RequestBody needs @Getter in Spring
I know about @RequestBody use deserialize concept of Jackson's ObjectMapper. Also I know Jackson ObjectMapper use Reflection.
Now the problem here is that reflection can set a private field, so I don't know why a getter is needed.
Of course, I know that Getter is used to retrieve the value of RequestBody.
What I'm really curious about is why do we need a Getter when mapping?

By default Jackson uses Java Bean properties to set or read values. Hence you need getters/setters to do such. You can switch Jackson to use fields instead of properties.

Ok I got it, But why use properties as the default strategy?? Is it because of encapsulation?

History and the fact that most DTO expose getters/setters anyway.
